# Regex, grep lines containing only 1 occurrences of a char

Tags: regex, grep, bigdata

I am looking for an efficient regular expression [(preferably possessive)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), which i can use to grep lines containing only one delimiter (',') from a big file (5Gb) :

E.G

```
X,Y
X1,Y1,Y2
X3,Y3
X4,Y4
X5,Y5,Z6
```

>>> grep "???" big_file

```
X,Y
X3,Y3
X4,Y4
```

Comment: Possessive quantifiers: one iteration over the data without backtracking: http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Comment: without regex: `awk -F, 'NF==2' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @Rawling (one of the answers here) is right and his regular expression is correct, it is still not possessive and therefore not optimized, he is correct that no backtracking will occur, but it will not be with the best performance *because the possessive quantifier doesn't have to remember any backtracking positions.* as was mentioned in the link attached in the question.

The following expression will be possessive and optimized, i will demonstrate together with the use of grep as was asked in the question:

> grep -E "^[^,]*+,[^,]*+$" big_data

Comment: What is the effect of the `+$` at the end of the expression? That's the only part I don't understand.

Comment: It is not `+$` that matters, but the `*+`. That `$` is just a simple end-of-line.

Comment: 1) `grep` with POSIX ERE (you are using `-E` flag) does not support possessive quantifiers. 2) `^[^,]*,[^,]*$` has the same complexity and performance as `^[^,]*+,[^,]*+$` because each subsequent subpattern cannot match at the same location inside the string - hence, no backtracking, not thought-up problems. Please accept Rawling's correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

Shouldn't a simple `^[^,]*,[^,]*$` avoid backtracking, because of the start/end-of-string markers?

Comment: Could you please explain it more clearly? I think regular expression can't store state like appearance numbers of some pattern because it's implemented by a final state machine, right? But why it works, I have check it with [http://rubular.com/](http://rubular.com/). Amazing!

Comment: Basically, this should never need to backtrack... It starts at the start, gets characters until it hits a comma, then gets more characters. If it finds a comma then, it's a fail; if it finds the end of the string, it's a pass.

Comment: why `[^,]*` means everything except `,`, rather then not `,` at first then everything is OK?

Comment: Please see my answer , and explanation why your answer is correct although not optimized one. +1 for correct answer